# Develop Application With ReactJS and Express.js Using Single Port And Double Port

Tags: reactjs, express

How can I develop application With ReactJS and Express.js Using Single Port And Double Port?

What are the benefits of developing an application using a single port vs double port?

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Using a single port makes development easier since you only have to start one service to get the application running. It takes more time to setup, but the payoff is worth it. If you are using express, you can compile, bundle and serve webpack bundles with the [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware). This combined with something like `nodemon` lets both your front end and backend code auto restart on changes.

Answer (score 0):

To take advantage of two ports you will want to do *HotReload* combined with your choice of code bundler. Hot Reload will inject your code as you save it so you can see the results of what you are doing nearly instant. It helps with developing a lot faster.

A popular code bundler is [webpack dev server with hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/).

However I know there is another one that gets a lot of good reviews called [parcel](https://parceljs.org/hmr.html). I hear that parcel is easier to get up and running and has a lower learning curve.

I personally use webpack, and there are lots of tutorials on getting it set up with react.

One port is all you need for production as the react app will just be javascript files.

So you will have one port for your express server, and while developing you will have the second port in use by either webpack dev server or your choice of dev server whether it be parcels or another.

Hope this helps you.